# mac stuck while re-installing xcode?

Tags: xcode

I recently had a problem with Xcode 3.2.6 and decided to reinstall it. I tried to uninstall the previous one before but wasn't able to. The instructions said to run a line in a terminal window but I kept getting the message that Xcode was not found. Anyway, I decided to do a not-so-clean reinstallation and clicked on the dmg to install it.
Everything went fine until now, there is a message that reads

"running package scripts"

"install time remaining: 2 min"

it has been like this for the last 20 minutes!!!!!! what should I do?????? should I force it to quit with activity monitor? should I wait longer?
HELP PLEASE!!!!!

Comment: maybe should be asked on programmers or superuser?

Comment: I fear 'patience is a virtue' - I seem to remember the XCode installs taking a very long time on my machines, with the timing quite badly underestimating the actual time.  If it is still a problem in an hour, then start worrying.  (It's a while since I installed XCode 3.x, but the XCode 4.x's took a while on my machine.)

Comment: Actually, I know now what happened... during the installation process it asked me to close iTunes, which I did, but the window asking for it remained opened. It occurred to me to check if there was something else from iTunes opened in the activity monitor, and there was! Stupid iTunes has an "iTunes helper" that opens automatically and doesn't close when you close iTunes.
I forced the helper to quit and that unblocked the installation process! I wanted to answer my question but don't have enough privileges to do it!

Comment: @Laura: Please post your comment as a solution. It works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I know now what happened... during the installation process it asked me to close iTunes, which I did, but the window asking for it remained opened. It occurred to me to check if there was something else from iTunes opened in the activity monitor, and there was! iTunes has an "iTunes helper" that opens automatically and doesn't close when you close iTunes. I forced the helper to quit and that unblocked the installation process!